# Existence and uniqueness for $t \geq 0$ for system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

recently I showed that if $f:[t_0,t_F] \times \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ suffices the condition for constant $\omega \geq 0$ that $\langle f(t,x), x \rangle \leq \omega ||x||_2^2$ for all $(t,x) \in [t_0,t_F] \times \Bbb R^n$ then the solutions to $$\dot{x} = f(t,x)$$ $$x(0) = x_0$$ are defined globally on the right side (meaning for all values to $\infty$). Now I am supposed to show that the system of equations $$\dot{u} = a-bu+u^2v-u$$ $$\dot{v} = bu-u^2v$$ for positive constants $a,b$ and $u_0,v_0>0$ has unique solutions which are defined for all $t \geq 0$ and stay positive. I tried to show that $\langle f(t,(u,v)),(u,v) \rangle \leq \omega ||(u,v)||_2^2$ to secure at least global existence on the right but I can't find constant to bound $$\langle f(t,(u,v)),(u,v) \rangle = au-bu^2+u^3v-u^2+buv-u^2v^2$$ since odd powers appear. I wanted to ask whether trying to apply the condition is correct because it seemed to me the only way (and may appreciate a tip for the upper bound).